# Stop Start Screen on W8 from minimizing on dual screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 Metro/Modern UI with Dual / Multiple Monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/483577/windows-8-metro-modern-ui-with-dual-multiple-monitors)

I'm running Windows 8 with two screens, and have set it so that I have Metro on my secondary screen, because I thought that I could have that visible while I was working on other things on the main screen. The problem is, as soon as I click on something on the main screen, Metro goes away on my secondary screen. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?? I would like to be able to see f.ex the clock, notifications on mail/messaging etc. while I'm working on things.

Comment: See also [Windows 8 Metro/Modern UI with Dual / Multiple Monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/483577/windows-8-metro-modern-ui-with-dual-multiple-monitors)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that question because that is about spanning the start screen across multiple monitors, while this one is about the behavior of the start screen when it is displayed on one monitor and you do something on the other.

Comment: It actually a duplicate of: [Windows 8 Metro UI with Multiple Monitors — Keep in always maximized?](http://superuser.com/questions/471825/windows-8-metro-ui-with-multiple-monitors-keep-in-always-maximized)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Metro" interface you are referring to is actually the Start screen. Just like the Start menu in previous versions of windows, once you focus elsewhere on the desktop, it closes. It carries over this behavior because it is essentially an evolution of the Start menu.

If you want to have a Metro app (not the Start screen) visible while using the regular Windows desktop, you can snap it to another monitor. You can only do this with one Metro app, however (if you have more than 2 monitors).

You can also snap a Metro app to the side of one screen and have the other part of the screen available for the Desktop or another Metro app. To do this, just put your mouse cursor on the top edge of the Metro app and drag it down, and then to the side of one of your monitors. It will snap it to the side of your screen, and you can then open other Metro apps, or the Desktop, in the larger space.

Comment: Ok, I see now. I have looked at this all wrong then. In my head, the Metro interface was a program, but it's really just an advanced menu. Now I see why it didn't work out as planned. Thank you for the enlightment!