# With dual monitors, is it possible to have 1 screen in Desktop mode and one screen showing the Start Screen?

Tags: windows-8

I'd like to be able to see all the info from my tiles while I am working.  Is it possible to make the Start Screen persist?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/a/494284/1087

Comment: Didn't see that one.  Although, that question didn't ask if we can make the Start Screen persist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 Metro/Modern UI with Dual / Multiple Monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/483577/windows-8-metro-modern-ui-with-dual-multiple-monitors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't stop this auto-minimize behavior. See the duplicate question [Stop Start Screen on W8 from minimizing on dual screens](https://superuser.com/q/494279/1087) for details.