# Automatic minimization of tiles on the second monitor

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 Metro/Modern Start Screen with Multiple Monitors — Keep it always maximized?](https://superuser.com/questions/471825/windows-8-metro-modern-start-screen-with-multiple-monitors-keep-it-always-max)

I wanted to ask. Everywhere in the pictures they show them on one monitor running "metro" and on the second desktop. I would like it too, but when I'm on one monitor and the desktop on the second metro, always when I click on the desktop or in the Explorer should I let him, so the subway on the second monitor automatically minimize. It is somehow set to "metro" display the time?

Comment: Would you care to clarify the latter half of your post? I couldn't really figure out what you want to do at all. You might want to take a look at [Windows 8 Metro/Modern UI with Dual / Multiple Monitors?](http://superuser.com/questions/483577/windows-8-metro-modern-ui-with-dual-multiple-monitors), [Stop Start Screen on W8 from minimizing on dual screens](http://superuser.com/questions/494279/stop-start-screen-on-w8-from-minimizing-on-dual-screens), [Windows 8 Metro UI with Multiple Monitors — Keep in always maximized?](http://superuser.com/questions/471825/windows-8-metro-ui-with-multipl) etc.